# if substring in string == False (boolean confusion)

Tags: python, boolean

Here's another beginner's question -

`if "&" in string:`
and
`if "&" in string != False:`

returns the same output, but the following generates a different result.

`if "&" in string == True:`

I undestand that I could just write `if "&" in string:`, but I am confused with the underlying logic as to why adding an ==True boolean would change the result.

Also, should I use `if "&" not in string` instead of `if "&" in string == False:`? What's the difference in logic?

Comment: Probably has to do with operator precedence issues. *In general*, it's considered bad practice to directly compare with the boolean `True` and `False`, for exactly this reason. Similarly `not in` is preferred over `(... in ...) == False`. Also, checking for whether something _equals_ true will break on any 'truthy' value that isn't true (for example, any non-empty string will evaluate to 'true' when used in the context of a boolean check, but it isn't literally equal to `True`)

Answer (score 1):

This is due to Python's condition chaining feature. Just as

```
if 1 < a < 10:
```

is equivalent to

```
if 1 < a and a < 10:
```

your example

```
if "&" in string == True:
```

is equivalent to

```
if "&" in string and string == True:
```

Since `string == True` can never be true, the combined condition is always False.

Add pareentheses to get what you want:

```
if ("&" in string) == True:
```

But testing a boolean with `== True` or `== False` is generally poor style. Just write

```
if "&" in string:
```

Comment: Values of different types *can* be equal (`3 == 3.0`, for example), but neither `str.__eq__` nor `bool.__eq__` allow for a `str` and a `bool` value to compare as equal.